# How to write a JUnit test to compare the equality of 2 lists of objects?

Tags: java, list, object, junit

I have written the following JUnit test but it was failed because my test is comparing the object references and not the object values:

```
public class ListSerializerTest {

  private InputStream iStream;
  private ByteArrayOutputStream oStream;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  }

  List<Position> serialzeAndDeserializeObject(List<Position> positionList) {
    Stream<Position> positionListStream = positionList.stream();
    OutputStreamUtil.<Position> serializeObjectsFromStream(positionList.size(), positionListStream,
        oStream, PositionSerializer::serialize);
    iStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oStream.toByteArray());
    List<Position> deserializedPositionList = new ArrayList<>();
    Consumer<Position> PositionListConsumer = position -> deserializedPositionList.add(position);
    InputStreamUtil.<Position> deserializeObjectsToConsumer(iStream, PositionListConsumer,
        PositionSerializer::deserialize);
    return deserializedPositionList;
  }

  @Test
  public void Equals_equal() {
    List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<Position>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      double x = Math.random();
      double y = Math.random();
      Position positionObject = new Position(x, y);
      positionList.add(positionObject);
    }
    List<Position> deserializedPositionList = serialzeAndDeserializeObject(positionList);
    assertThat(deserializedPositionList).isEqualTo(positionList);
  }
}
```

How to make it compare object values instead of object references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely missing correct `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the `Position` class. You need a test like:

```
Position a = new Position(1d, 1d);
Position b = new Position(1d, 1d);
assertThat(a).isEqualTo(b);
```

Your assumption about the assertions is incorrect, your test is not comparing using references. In AssertJ the `isEqualTo()` method in:

```
assertThat(deserializedPositionList).isEqualTo(positionList);
```

> Verifies that the actual value is equal to the given one.

which is performed by calling the `ArrayList.equals()` method under the hood. To compare the lists by their reference one uses `isSameAs()`:

```
assertThat(deserializedPositionList).isSameAs(positionList);
```

> Verifies that the actual value is the same as the given one, ie using == comparison

which is performing the check with `==` operator as in `deserializedPositionList == positionList`.